# How are seu control characters bph and sci added to create white and blue text?

Tags: editor, ibm-midrange, control-characters

How are seu control characters bph and sci added to create white and blue text? Whats the simplest way to do this? Is there a better approach to coloring text when using RDi?

Using Google found a variety of techniques:

[How to change color of source lines - midrange.com](https://archive.midrange.com/rpg400-l/200008/msg00078.html)

[Color lines in SEU - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.sys.ibm.as400.misc/Dvx4YKtSZKA)

Comment: Adding "color" to source by physical insertion of ctl-chars should be avoided. The effect of those chars in cross-platform source edits when using various IDEs can be problematic. Different platforms and CCSID conversions can be messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Do not use SEU***, it was stabilized a v6.1. v6.1 went out of support on 9/30/2015. Instead use RDi which colors source automatically without control codes. In fact, the control codes you use to color SEU text will appear as strange characters in RDi.

Alternatively, https://miworkplace.com/ provides a simpler, less costly UI. But it also automatically colors your code.